# Number of badges should be a link

Tags: feature-request, badges, usability

I think that the number of badges in the top-most menu bar should link to https://ux.stackexchange.com/badges

[image]

I'm sure I'm not the only one who at least once clicked them to get to the aforementioned page (and I'm not even a novice SE user...)

Comment: I assume you mean the pages page for the user; in which case I agree that it should do that just as the reputation count does the same. They should both act the same; either both are links or neither is a link. On that note, why is the behavior different on meta.ux? Clicking the rep count here does _not_ link to user rep, whereas it does link to user rep on the main site.

Answer (score 4):

That's the badges overview for all users. Wouldn't it be better to see just your badges (eg. the section of your profile dedicated to badges)?

Comment: In that case the heading of the Badges section of the profile should link to the badges overview page... Right now there is no way to get to the badges overview page without going through the main menu, and I wouldn't be surprised if most people ignore the whole menu, or at least the badges section for a long time.

Comment: I agree with Rahul; the number refers to *your* badges in the same way that the rep text refers to *your* rep. Since the rep text links to the user's profile with `?tab=reputation`, the badges text should link to the user's profile with `?tab=badges`