# Rep count in meta.UX is not a link like on UX.SE

Tags: feature-request, reputation, hyperlinks, meta

[As reported by Ben Brocka on this issue](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/467/number-of-badges-should-be-a-link#comment857_467), the rep count shown in the header in meta is not a link, whereas the same text *is* a link in the standard UX Stack Exchange.

I would expect the links in the header to behave identically whether I'm in meta or main.

Comment: Never noticed that before. I'm betting Meta just doesn't have the page it goes to since Meta doesn't have separate reputation